# How can I get the last merged branch name in git

Tags: linux, git, github, gitlab

How can i get the last merged branch name in git from the remote

Tried

git log --first-parent --merges -1 --oneline

But not getting the branch name

Please help

Comment: I agree with the answer that says: "If you think you need a branch name here, you are probably doing something wrong." It might help if you explained why you want to know the branch name, and perhaps we could provide another way to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 4):

In general, you cannot.

A merge commit may have, as its commit message, text of the form *merge branch foo* or *merge branch foo of someurl*, but to read that message, you must obtain the commit from the remote.  Even so, there's no guarantee that branch *foo* exists any more, or that the name means anything if it does exist.  Merging really works by commit hash IDs, not by branch names; branch names may evanesce.

If you think you need a branch name here, you are probably doing something wrong.  Branch names *do* make sense here in *other* version control systems, but in Git, depending on them is unwise.

Comment: Ok then, if you think there is no use-case, how would you handle the situation: you have a pull request from a branch that has a feature/bugfix prefix. Those prefixes influence versioning (package.json). You don't want to update the build version during the PR because if the pipeline fails, you have version-update-commits that you need to undo and the devs need to pull and merge before pushing again. So you want to run version-update only after merging the PR (dev branch update build). But at that point you don't know what was the last merge - a feature or a bugfix. Now how do you +version?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the command you need to give (change the branch name from origin/master to whichever branch you're checking merges for):

```
git log --merges origin/master --oneline --grep='^Merge' -1 | grep -oe "[^']*[^']" | sed -n 2p
```

Comment: git log --merges origin/master --oneline --grep='^Merge' -1
7051bf7 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merged in major/1 (pull request #3)
not getting the branch name

Answer (score 1):

I had quite a bit of a hard time trying to solve this issue.
I had to get this information for my CircleCi pipeline, and to solve my problem I used the GitHub cli.
Specifically the `pr list` command: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_list

The following command gives you all the information of the last PR you merged into main
`gh pr list -s merged -B main -L 1`

Then you need to manipulate the string and get only the branch name. Which is the text before "MERGED"
I took it splitting the string and taking the penultimate element.